# Does /*+ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION */ work inside of a view creation in vertica?

Tags: sql, vertica, sql-view

I have very complicated SQL that starts out with the WITH statement in Vertica.  It fails without the materialization because of resource constraints, but runs in < 20 seconds with the materialization.  Then I put it into a create view statement.  It appears to lose the materialization as part of the view.  That's pretty frustrating.  The documentation doesn't mentioned any limitations of using it inside a view.

```
create view view_name as
with /*+ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION */  
report_quarters as
```

Answer (score 1):

From this part of the Vertica documentation:

https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/CREATEVIEW.htm

CREATE VIEW

Defines a view. Views are read only, so they do not support insert, update, delete, or copy operations.

The `/*+ENABLE_WITH_CLAUSE_MATERIALIZATION */` hint actually triggers a `CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE ...` process in the background. And that involves not only DML, like insert, update, delete and copy, but also DDL., and that is why it is not supported at this time.

A possible way of working around this, from Version 11.0.1 on, might be to use a stored procedure that:

- creates a `LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE` out of the WITH clause that you want to materialize.
- creates a target table, using `CREATE TABLE new AS SELECT ..FROM temp_table, etc.

The end user can call the stored procedure, then select from the newly created table.

Comment: Thanks.  I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.  I've had to go the temp table route for now.